# Define functions based on procedures stored in list

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm new to Scheme and functional programming in general and I'm just starting to write something more complicated. I was wondering if it was possible to define functions based on procedures that are stored in a list.

Let's say we have the following list of other lists that represent procedures (+ 2 3) and (* 3 4):

```
'((+ 2 3) (* 3 4))
```

Now I want to write something that would take in any list representing procedure (for example *(+ 2 3)*) and define a function based on it that I can use later on.

So if I were to pick (+ 2 3), I'd want the following function to be declared:

```
(define (funct_name) (+ 2 3))
```

So basically, what I'm looking for is a function that would define other functions and it must be written in the script. So perhaps something like this?

```
(define (def_functions_fromlist) ls) ;this would define the function  
;corresponding to procedure in ls
```

Thank you in advance and I'm sorry if I seem too confused here.

Comment: `(define (funct_name) (+ 2 3))` is not a function. Do you mean `(lambda () (+ 2 3))`?

Comment: @Unlocked Oh... I thought that define defines a function, that's what I was told in my intro course, at least. It might be a little bit offtopic, but what's the difference between the two expressions?

Comment: `(define)` defines a variable, but has a special form for defining functions. `(lambda)` is a function. `(define (f x) x)` is shorthand for `(define f (lambda (x) x))`.

They weren't lying to you when they said that `(define)` defines a function, but it also does more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return an anonymous function that evaluates the list, as so:

```
(define (def-prod-from ls)
    (lambda () (eval ls)))
```

This will work for any input, not just lists. That could be an issue, but probably isn't.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.